# Binary Search Tree - adding every node into one result

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I try to add every node into one result in iterate way in Java.
For example: if I have a root 5 which has got right node = 7 and left node=3 the result is 15.
I've tried in many ways but I don't know how not to miss any node when my tree is extensive.

I would be grateful for every tip.

Comment: You need to provide an attempt to solve the problem to get answers that can either solidify your approach or propose new ones

Comment: please provide us with your attempt (code) so we can help you in a more efficient way

Comment: I'm still trying to do something quite good but everything I've made totally haven't work so I deleted everything to looking for new way....

Answer (score 0):

Look up tree traversals. There are three basic types: in-order, pre-order, and post-order. Essentially you need to create a function that accepts a node as a parameter and returns an integer.

Assuming you have a node like this:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *right, *left;
}
```

Something like this would do the trick.

```
int tree_sum(Node *root) {
    if (root == nullptr) return 0; // stops recursion. occurs at leaves
    return root->value + tree_sum(root->left) + tree_sum(root->right);
}
```

Call the function on the root of your tree. This is known as a pre-order traversal. I wrote the code in C++ because I don't know Java.

For tree traversal without recursion use a stack as described here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/

Comment: Thank you but it is the recursive way, I need iterate (some loops etc).

Comment: @HappyProgrammer I changed the answer with a link to your solution